# Questions about routine recommendation

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, questions

Take this question for example [Good workout split for absolute beginner with Planet Fitness equipment? (skinny want to build muscle whole-body)](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/45223/good-workout-split-for-absolute-beginner-with-planet-fitness-equipment-skinny)

I started thinking out an answer for it, then realised that there's actually a lot to address in the question, and it's pretty much all opinion based.

We tend to close questions that are opinion based as they don't have solid answers, which got me thinking that many of the routine based questions (recommend a routine, critique my routine, etc, etc) are opinion based.

I don't like bodybuilding style training splits, so I'll always lean towards more strength based stuff, yet bro splits do seem to work for some people, so my answer to a question like this is based on my opinion.

Should questions like this be closed as opinion based as there's no single good answer?

(personally, I think no, because a person has come here seeking help, and they could get some very good advice, even though it is "opinion based")

Answer (score 3):

I don't really see a reason to close it as opinion-based. I agree that the user is well-intentioned, and we do indeed have the know-how to help them.

I don't even really see it as an opinionated thing. The objectively correct answer should include something to the effect of

> Any tried-and-true program will work for you if you just pick one and stick with it.

And then the answerer can go on to provide resources on some of these tried-and-true programs, and optionally round it off with an opinion on which program they would personally choose, and why.

If it's closeable, it's more likely to be as a duplicate. I'm sure there are similar questions whose answers would satisfy this one as well.

Comment: To add, this has been asked many times in various forms, it is possible we could close as duplicates, or pick one and turn it into a community wiki detailing various plans and point questions to that.